# How do I structure classes to fit this type of gui system?

Tags: c#, user-interface

I am currently trying to code a gui library in love2dcs,
however, I was wondering how I would go about structuring classes in a way so that I can declare gui elements like this..

```
public static class Editor
{
  Window MainWindow
  public static void Init()
  {
    MainWindow = new Window("Window0", "", 0, 0, 256, 240) //List of Widgets
    {
        new Window("Window1", "", 0, 0, 256, 240), //List of Widgets
        new Window("Window2", "", 0, 0, 256,  16)  //List of Widgets
        {
            //String
            new TextEdit("TextEdit1", "Hello", 0, 0,256, 16) = "HelloWorld0" 
        }
    };

    //1st way to check for window2 press
    GetWidget("Window2").Pressed += OnWindow2Pressed()
  } 

  public static void Update()
  {
    MainWindow.Update();

    //2nd way to check for window2 press
    if (MainWindow.IsPressed("Window2"))
    {
      GetWidget("TextEdit1").Value = "HelloWorld1!";
    }
  }

  public static void Render()
  {
    MainWindow.Render();
  }

  private static void OnWindow2Pressed()
  {
    Window window2 = GetWidget("Window2");
    GetWidget("Window2").Add
    (
       new TextEdit("TextEdit1", "Hello", 0, 0+(window2.Value.Count*16), 256, 16) = "HelloWorld3"
    );
  }
}
```

if anyone knows how to do this and can post some code on how to setup the widget class to accept type parameters so this works I would be very thankful

**EDIT**: this is more of a class structure question then a how do I do it question

the issue here is I cannot directly inherit from List because I would need to specify both widget type and value type

**EDIT2**: so there is a attempt at doing it however it doesn't like that I am trying to implicitly cast to a Window from a WidgetList.

```
    public class WidgetList : List<Widget>
    {
        public Widget Widget { get; set; }

        public WidgetList(Widget widget)
        {
            widget = Widget;
        }
        public static implicit operator Widget(WidgetList widgetList)
        {
            return widgetList.Widget;
        }
    }

    public class Widget
    {
        //Child Widgets
        public Widget Parent { get; private set; } = null;
        public WidgetList Children { get; private set; } = null;

        //Callers
        private                Widget(string name, string text, int x, int y, int w, int h)
        {
            Children = new WidgetList(this);

            Name = name;
            Text = text;
            X = x;
            Y = y;
            W = w;
            H = h;
            OnCreate();
        }
        public  static WidgetList New(string name, string text, int x, int y, int w, int h)
        {
            return new WidgetList(new Widget(name, text, x, y, w, h));
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public static Window Window;
        public static void Do()
        {
            Window = Window.New("Window0", "", 0, 0, 256, 240) //List of Widgets
            {
                Window.New("Window1", "", 0, 0, 256, 240), //List of Widgets
                Window.New("Window1", "", 0, 0, 256, 240)  //List of Widgets
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: I never used this library so I'm just guessing. Ctrl+Click to go into the MainWindow source, see if it implements any interfaces(eg. --IMainWindow/..etc..), try to create an IEnnumerable<IMainWindow>. Find something that max. diff types of elements implement (..like TextEdit etc.. )

Comment: is IEnumerable what I am looking for? can I pass it's value type like so? `IEnumerable<ValueType>`

Comment: do u want to do something like this `List<Window> wList = new List<Window>();wList.Add(new Window("Window0", "", 0, 0, 256, 240));` ? Are `values` the strings inside the window ?

Comment: no I want to have the exact same syntax as I posted. basically where the widget is a list of widgets but also has a value type. the class would inherit from Widget<ValueType> or if it inherited from a button it would be Button<ValueType>. idk if this is even possible but if so that's how I want to do it

Comment: I would say write down exactly what ur thinking below ur code even if it doesn't compile. At least someone will be able to convert it to compilable code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an attempt to improve what you're trying to do.
I could help more if I knew what the library looked like, I've just made a Mock library to make the rest of the design.
Maybe someone can take over from here and give a better suggestion.

DON'T DO THIS: --  `public class WidgetList : List<Widget>`
unless you really want to improve something that exists in the c# `List` class

If you make the Widgets take a type parameter you'll run into co-variance and contravariance issues later, as you won't be able to add child widgets to a list of parent widgets.

```
    public interface ILibraryWidget
    {
        void OnInit();
        void Update();
        void Render();
    }

    public abstract class BaseWidget : ILibraryWidget
    {
        public void OnInit()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Render()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Update()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class Window : ILibraryWidget
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }
        public int W { get; set; }
        public int H { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }

        public Window()
        {

        }
        public void OnInit()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Im init");
        }
        public void Update()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Im update");
        }

        public void Render()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Im render");
        }
    }

    public class TextEdit : Window
    {
        public TextEdit()
        {

        }
        public new void OnInit()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Im init text");
        }
        public new void Update()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Im update text");
        }

        public new void Render()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Im render text");
        }
    }

    public class Widget
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }
        public int W { get; set; }
        public int H { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }

        private Window Package { get; set; }

        public delegate void Pressed();

        //Child Widgets
        public Widget Parent { get; private set; }
        public List<Widget> Children { get; private set; }


        //Callers
        public Widget()
        {
            Children = new List<Widget>();
        }

        public void OnInit()
        {
            (Package as Window).OnInit();
        }
        public void Update()
        {
            (Package as Window).Update();
        }

        public void Render()
        {
            (Package as Window).Render();
        }

        public static List<Widget> New(string name, string text, int x, int y, int w, int h)
        {
            return new List<Widget> {
                new Widget { Name = name, Text = text, X = x, Y = y, W = w, H = h }
            };
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Widget testWidget = new Widget
            {
                Name = "Window0",
                Text = "",
                X = 0,
                Y = 0,
                W = 256,
                H = 240,

                //List of Widgets
                Children = new List<Widget>
                {
                    new Widget{ Name = "Window0_0", Text = "", X = 0, Y = 0, W = 256, H = 240, },
                    new Widget{ Name = "Window0_1", Text = "", X = 0, Y = 0, W = 256, H = 240, }
                }

            };

        }
    }
```